# retrieve a specific part of the ajax response and put it in a variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to get a particular part of the Ajax response and put this text in a variable. In this case var number. When I use this code the alert comes up null.

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('a.productnamecolor.colors_productname').each(function(){
var star_link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: star_link,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        var number = $(data).find("#pt691").text();
        alert(number);
        } 
    }) 
}); 
});
```

Below is just a small portion of the total response that is returned. I want to capture the "2" in the span id pt691 and put that in the variable number. Does .text() not work in this case?

```
<span class="PageText_L691n">Based on <span id="pt691">2</span> reviews </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work OK for me http://jsfiddle.net/K7VBp/1/ and I can use `.text()` or `.html()` with equal success. Can we see the full result of your `data` variable?

Comment: funny thing is I tried it again and now it works as posted above. perhaps I had a typo the first time and I corrected it when posting it here. thanks for checking it in jsfiddle.