# Why is my attempt to return only part of the html ajax response failing in C#.net environment?

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor, asp.net-webpages

Here is my $.ajax function:

```
$("div#eventBox").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/AJAX Pages/Test.cshtml",
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (response) {
            $("div#eventBox").html($(response).find("#bodyP").text());
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
            alert("The AJAX function didn't work.");
        }
    });
});
```

Problem is here (taken from above snippet):

```
$("div#eventBox").html($(response).find("#bodyP").text());
```

But according to solutions found here:

[retrieve a specific part of the ajax response and put it in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926503/retrieve-a-specific-part-of-the-ajax-response-and-put-it-in-a-variable)

And here;

[Select only part of a HTML page with jQuery's .post() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715859/select-only-part-of-a-html-page-with-jquerys-post-method)

My code should work.

The error I get in the JavaScript console is (this will also reveal the html of the target ajax page):

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div id="eventPageWrapper" style="margin: auto; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
    <span style="text-align: center; margin: 5px 10px;">Harlem Ambassadors-Basketball Fundraiser for American Red Cross</span></br>
    <p id="bodyP" style="text-align: center; margin: 5px 10px;">
        The Harlem Ambassadors Basketball team will be in Okmulgee today for a fundraiser for the American Red Cross. It will be held at the Brock Gymnasium and starts at 4:00 p.m. Tickets are on sale now and can be purchased through the American Red Cross. Advanced tickets are $8.00 per student and $10.00 per adult. If the tickets are purchased at the door, they are $10.00 per student and $12.00 per adult. Contact the American Red Cross for tickets or more information at (918)-756-0966 or (918)-932-7323.
    </p>
</div>
```

This is likely a simple solution, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

I found the source of my white space and it was easy to eliminate using simple html comments.

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}<!--  HERE WAS WHERE ALL THE WHITE SPACE WAS COMING FROM BEFORE I ADDED THIS COMMENT
--><div id="eventPageWrapper" style="margin: auto; text-align: center; width: 100%;">
    <span style="text-align: center; margin: 5px 10px;">Harlem Ambassadors-Basketball Fundraiser for American Red Cross</span></br>
    <p id="bodyP" style="text-align: center; margin: 5px 10px;">
        The Harlem Ambassadors Basketball team will be in Okmulgee today for a fundraiser for the American Red Cross. It will be held at the Brock Gymnasium and starts at 4:00 p.m. Tickets are on sale now and can be purchased through the American Red Cross. Advanced tickets are $8.00 per student and $10.00 per adult. If the tickets are purchased at the door, they are $10.00 per student and $12.00 per adult. Contact the American Red Cross for tickets or more information at (918)-756-0966 or (918)-932-7323.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Most likely your `response` has a character at the beginning that isn't `<`

Comment: Well, I have no problem getting this response page back from ajax if I'm not trying to target a single element. The first character (after C# is done rendering it) is `<`

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a newline, return, tab, or space? that's the only way the error you're getting can happen. That error says the selector is an invalid selector, meaning jQuery interpreted it as a selector rather than html.

Comment: you can sent a variable of type boolean in ajax `data:{onlyText=True}` which server will check and return only text instead of all current respond

Comment: @Epsil0neR I don't get the syntax there. I thought I did, but I get syntax errors when I try to include that in my `$.ajax` function

Comment: sorry, correct syntax would be `data:{onlyText:true}`. data must keep variables in array. Try now.

Comment: Well thanks to everyone's help I found the source of my white-space and eliminated it. I will update my post above to at least show anyone in the future where this white space might be coming from in the WebMatrix web-pages environment.

Comment: @Epsil0neR Oh, okay, I will try that and get right back with you. You should post this as an alternative answer to Kevin B's (not that his is bad).

Comment: @Epsil0neR No matter how I try your code snippet, it seems to be incorrect syntax. After researching online, I don't think there is a `data:{onlyText:true}` option. Are you sure you've got the right language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way instead:

```
$("#eventBox").html( $("<div>").html(response).find("#bodyP").text() );
```

the `$()` method can't accept html strings that don't start with `<`

also fixed your eventBox selector.

Comment: interesting. It seems a simple `console.log(response)` reveals that I have a ton of white space before my first selector. This is caused due to the C# code block I need to reset the `Layout` of the page. I wonder if there is a `.trim()` method for jQuery that works as well as C#'s

Comment: May I ask why `$("#eventBox")` is preferable to `$("div#eventBox")`?

Comment: because #eventBox must be unique, therefore since there is only one of them on your page, it makes sense to select it directly by ID so that jQuery will use `document.getElementByID()` instead of `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Oh, nice! I did not know that. `document.getElementById()` will undoubtedly be faster. I will be keeping this in mind from now on.

Comment: Selecting classes works the same way, however, the speed difference is much smaller (and sometimes goes in the opposite direction)

Comment: Is there any way that you can force the AJAX request to return only text, like what Epsil0neR was saying? His syntax is not fitting in my `.$ajax` function without errors. I would rather not have to force an extra `<div>` into every element I want to return ajax to.

Comment: well, it isn't forcing an extra div into it, you're just using the div to make selecting the element more consistent. But yes, you could modify your service to only return text.

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation on how to return text only from the `.ajax` function. Epsil0neR's answer doesn't seem to work. Can you think of anything?

Comment: Remove the html from the server-side script.